# How to get values of penultimate layer in convolutional neural network(CNN)?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to implement CNN for a classification task. I want to see the how the weights are being optimized at each epoch. To do so, I need the values of penultimate layer. Also, I will hard code the last layer and backpropagation myself.  Please recommend APIs also which which will be helpful.

**Edit:** I have added a code from keras examples. Looking forward to edit it.
[This](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer) link provide some hint. I have mentioned the layer after which I require the output.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from keras.preprocessing import sequence
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D
from keras.datasets import imdb

# set parameters:
max_features = 5000
maxlen = 400
batch_size = 100
embedding_dims = 50
filters = 250
kernel_size = 3
hidden_dims = 250
epochs = 100

print('Loading data...')
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=max_features)
print(len(x_train), 'train sequences')
print(len(x_test), 'test sequences')

print('Pad sequences (samples x time)')
x_train = sequence.pad_sequences(x_train, maxlen=maxlen)
x_test = sequence.pad_sequences(x_test, maxlen=maxlen)
print('x_train shape:', x_train.shape)
print('x_test shape:', x_test.shape)

print('Build model...')
model = Sequential()

# we start off with an efficient embedding layer which maps
# our vocab indices into embedding_dims dimensions
model.add(Embedding(max_features,
                    embedding_dims,
                    input_length=maxlen))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

# we add a Convolution1D, which will learn filters
# word group filters of size filter_length:
model.add(Conv1D(filters,
                 kernel_size,
                 padding='valid',
                 activation='relu',
                 strides=1))
# we use max pooling:
model.add(GlobalMaxPooling1D())

# We add a vanilla hidden layer:
model.add(Dense(hidden_dims))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

# We project onto a single unit output layer, and squash it with a sigmoid:
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid')) #<======== I need output after this. 



model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the individual layers of your model like this:

```
num_layer = 7 # Dense(1) layer
layer = model.layers[num_layer]
```

> I want to see the how the weights are being optimized at each epoch.

To get the weights of the layer use `layer.get_weights()` like this:

```
w, b = layer.get_weights() # weights and bias of Dense(1)
```

> I need the values of penultimate layer.

To get the value of the evaluation of the last layer use `model.predict()`:

```
prediction = model.predict(x_test)
```

To get the evaluation of any other layer do it with tensorflow like this:

```
input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32) # Create input placeholder
layer_output = layer(input) # create layer output operation

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer() # initialize variables

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init_op)

    # evaluate layer output
    output = sess.run(layer_output, feed_dict = {input: x_test})
    print(output)
```

Comment: I want to get output of penultimate layer i.e before it enters last layer. Actually I want to use my own optimiser instead of using any optimiser provided by keras. I think the penultimate layer output would be output of   `model.add(Activation('relu'))` layer. So for 25000 datapoints I would get ouput of 25000 * 250, I think. Correct me I am wrong somewhere.

Comment: The last bit of my answer will let you do that, make sure to use the right layer `layer = model.layers[8]`. Then `layer_output` is a tensor, so you can continue adding your logic with pure tensorflow.

Comment: I used the code the I mentioned in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46885680/why-different-intermediate-layer-ouput-of-cnn-in-keras), to get the intermediate layer output.